# Lua: How do I read from a list of numbers

Tags: lua, lua-table

I have a function which does all the magic for me and controls a motor.

This reduces my programming to this one line...

```
Set_RPM_With_Acceleration_Value( 200, 15)
```

In the example shown, the motor will spin up to 200 RPM, with an acceleration value of 15

I'm testing the `stop/start/interrupt/restart` capability of the system hardware and software.

I now want to run the test with different values given to the function; e.g.,,,

```
Set_RPM_With_Acceleration_Value( 200, 15)
Set_RPM_With_Acceleration_Value(  50, 09)
Set_RPM_With_Acceleration_Value( 400, 20)
Set_RPM_With_Acceleration_Value( 500, 25)
```

I want to encapsulate this into a loop which...

- Reads two numbers (from a table ? Idunno, advise me)
- Gives me those two numbers in two variables
- Lets me call the function using those names, and not hard coded numbers

e.g.,  where I'm currently doing this...

```
Set_RPM_With_Acceleration_Value( 200, 15)
```

I would like to do this...

```
Set_RPM_With_Acceleration_Value( RPM_Value, Acceleration_Value)
```

How do I set up the numbers, and how do I read from the table ?

For that matter, is a table the right way to think about this ?

Does there exist such a thing in Lua as a *table of tables* ?

This will be for automated machine testing. We do **NOT** want a human involved at the keyboard or mouse.

On the other hand, it is quite desirable for me to hand code the values in the table once, ahead of time, before the script runs. I want to see what happens with various combinations of RPM, Acceleration, Power Drop Outs, etc.

Comment: As for the *table of tables*, this is actually pretty simple: 
`t = { { 200, 15 }, { 50, 9 }, { 400, 20 }, { 500, 25 } }`. You can also give names to the values: `t = { RPM = 200, accel = 15 } }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
V={
200, 15,
 50, 09,
400, 20,
500, 25,
}

for i=1,#V,2 do
    local RPM_Value = V[i]
    local Acceleration_Value = V[i+1]
    Set_RPM_With_Acceleration_Value(RPM_Value, Acceleration_Value)
end
```

Comment: First little examination and test looks good, will implement and let you know more within the hour. Thanks !!!

Comment: I thought it would be an hour; turned into an all-day affair. Anyway, yes, that works. In fact, I will have to have 3 numbers per test, RPM, Acceleration, and SpinUp time, and I may need a coast down time; in which case, I just put the numbers in triplets and quads instead of pairs, and increment the iteration by 3 or 4 as appropriate. Thanks. Nice Brain. 5 or 10 points to you; or whatever it's worth.